# Pandas DataFrame elegantly merging with csv file in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What's the most elegant way to merge several Pandas DataFrames (DF) from different dictionaries?

I have two dictionaries which I use to create several different DFs.  The first dictionary I use to create a DF from a list inside each key.  The second dictionary I use to outline the characteristics of a DF, for a read_csv approach on different text files.  All DFs have a common column called 'FN'.  SO I am looking to merge all combinations of DataFrame between the two dictionaries.

```
Dict1={List1:{'List_data':[some_data],
              'Match_txt_ID':'Textfilename'},
       List2:{'List_data':[some_data],
              'Match_txt_ID':'Textfilename'},
       }
Dict2={Filetype1:{'CSV_Endswith:'part_of_filename1',
              'Other_data':'Some_data'},
       Filetype2:{'CSV_Endswith':'part_of_filename2',
              'Other_data':'Some_data'},
       }
```

So ultimately using Pandas I am looking to merge the following combinations below using dictionaries Dict1 and Dict2 to help.

```
List1+Filetype1
List2+Filetype1
List1+Filetype2
List2+Filetype2
```

Meanwhile all this would be done in a loop.  So I would merge List1+Filetype1 and perform some stats gathering (then post stats to Excel), then List2+Filetype1 and perform some more stats gathering (then post stats to Excel).

I have the component parts below, but I don't know how to efficiently loop through by joining the three steps below.

```
for csvfile in os.listdir(some_directory):
    if csvfile.endswith('.txt'):
        for key in Dict2:
            if Dict2[key]['CSV_Endswith'] in csvfile:
                csv2df = pd.read_csv(csvfile,sep=';')
                Dict2_DF = DataFrame(csv2df)

for key in Dict1:
    Dict1_DF = DataFrame(Dict1[key]['List_data'])       

MERGED_DF = pd.merge(Dict1_DF, Dict2_DF, on=['FN'], how='outer')
#do stuff with MERGED_DF
```

Thanks

Comment: IIUC, my guess is that it doesn't matter, in the sense that basically any way you do it will have the time dominated by other stuff (reads, merges), so it doesn't really matter how you iterate.

Comment: With "efficiently" do you mean elegantly/clean code-wise? Else Ami's reply says it all, the iteration process itself is irrelevant in comparison to the merge process.

Comment: Hi Gecko, yeah I mean clean code wise, i'm not too sure where to cleanly start when iterating over two different dict keys in one loop, and i'm keen not to make a mess of it from the start :)